# Stack Overflow with 764,309+ questions and 1M+ answers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Could the best questions and answers be selected, edited and published into useful reference documentation?

Comment: This is probably better asked on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: That's kind of like asking if the best Wikipedia articles could be selected, edited and published. It defeats the purpose, all entries are continuously being better-organized and refined.

Comment: @Rex: that, of course, depends -- if "the purpose" is to provide the best answers in the best way, you're quite right. If "the purpose" is to make money off of other peoples' work, the answer may be rather different.

Comment: @Rex: One small problem with your argument: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Version_1.0_Editorial_Team)

Comment: @wai That doesn't really mean it's a good idea; I don't see why anyone would want either when there's the unabridged, instantly searchable version available for free

Answer (score 4):

Will the Stack Exchange team do it themselves? I doubt it. It would require a lot of manpower without much benefit for them. It's a lot of stuff to comb through to select the cream of the crop.

Can it be done by someone who has the time/money? Sure! Anyone is allowed to make a book with Stack Overflow questions and answers, so long as it is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike license.

Comment: Exactly. "Best" can be translated into "highest voted" questions (or however else you prefer).

Comment: @rlbusa Eh..., not exactly. A good portion of those aren't great material: [840 votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon), [831 votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke), etc.

Comment: maybe those threads could be spun off into their own book, and published just in time for xmas so that my wife can buy a copy for me.

Comment: Ugh, going back to single-keyword-based search in a different physical part of the book?  Advanced search functions or no sale.